# Hooks are not working on updateOne when using Typegoose only for save operations are called

Tags: mongodb, typescript, mongoose, typegoose

I've already created this and been using this Model. But now I've added  `@pre<Offer>("save"` as i want to do a few checks to the data before saving and adjust the values accordingly.

My problem is that when i do an update first the console logs never get output. Then I can't ever set `this.isOfferLive = false;` if i post `isOfferLive:true` so the `pre` is never called

What am i missing you?

I am using

```
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
    "typegoose": "^5.7.2",
    "mongoose": "^5.6.3",
emitDecoratorMetadata and experimentalDecorators are be enabled in tsconfig.json
```

One thing I noticed is that the `hooks` get called on `Model.create` but not on `Model.updateOne` when looking at the consoe logs.

How do i make them also work on Update

My class

```
@pre<Offer>("save", function(next: HookNextFunction) {
  console.log("[**** save]: " + this.isOfferLive);
  this.isOfferLive = false;
  if (!isOfferValid(this)) {
    this.isOfferLive = false;
  }
  next();
})
export class Offer extends Typegoose {
  @prop({ required: true, default: false })
  public isOfferLive: boolean;
}

export const Model = new Offer().getModelForClass(Offer);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: Found a way to update it, but its not documented & i dont recommend it!:

```
import * as mongoose from "mongoose";
import { pre, prop, Typegoose } from "./typegoose/src/typegoose";

@pre<Offer>("updateOne", function(this: mongoose.Query<any>) {
    // @ts-ignore
    this._update.isOfferLive = true;
    return;
})
class Offer extends Typegoose {
    @prop({ required: true, default: false })
    public isOfferLive: boolean;
}
const OfferModel = new Offer().getModelForClass(Offer);

(async () => {
    mongoose.set("debug", true);
    await mongoose.connect(`mongodb://mongodb:27017/`, {
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useFindAndModify: true,
        useCreateIndex: true,
        dbName: "verify315",
        user: "user",
        pass: "passwd",
        authSource: "admin",
        autoIndex: true
    });

    const dummy = new OfferModel();
    await dummy.save();

    await dummy.updateOne(dummy).exec();

    const dummyback = await OfferModel.findById(dummy._id).exec(); // re-fetch because otherwise it does not load the changes
    console.log("after updateOne:", dummyback);

    await mongoose.disconnect();
})();
```